# Why is it that most amp makers come from the UK and most guitar makers from the USA?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

At least from all the established brands it seems that most big amp companies come from the UK and most guitar makers come from the US why is that? Fender amps being the exception.

I know later on mesa came around and the uk does produce some boutique guitars, but for mega brands it does seem to be true, why?

Comment: Hendrix, Clapton, Page, Beck… Marshall amp, American guitar. That's more advertising than any company could ever pay for.

Comment: Might as well ask why one country produces more cars,  or  LCD displays,  or books of poetry.   An awful lot of the reason is  a combination of "who get there first"  and "tipping-point" statistics.

Comment: Mesa Boogie, Fender, there have been plenty of fine amps from the US...

Comment: What defines a "mega brand"?  It seems very opinion based.  If you could back it up with some stats, like 75% all amps used professionally are UK and 75% of all guitars purchased world wide are US you'd have a good question.  As is it seems opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it all started when Fender made the old tweed Bassman amp and Marshall attempted to copy it using parts that were available in the U.K. As a result, the Marshall had increased gain and guitar players loved it. But while Britain had Vox, America had Fender, Magnatone, Gibson amps to power their electrics for decades before Americans ever heard of Marshall and Vox. About the same time as americans were introduced to Marshall, a bunch of new solid state amps became available in America. Standell and Peavy come to mind. About the same time, Sunn became available to electric players in the U.S. My point here is that the  U.S. has had it's fair share of amp manufacturers, both tube and solidstate, and I'm not trying to diminish the value of British or European amps at all. but to say the U.K. has cornered the market on amplifiers is just not true, and we aren't even discussing the Japanese amps that are available these days.

Comment: I neglected to mention Ampeg, Silvertone, Alamo, and who knows where Danelectro amps were made.